# truncate a log file to zero while another process is continuously writing to it

Tags: files, cygwin

I'm trying to debug this horribly [hacky little program](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/18694/2381) and it's writing a trace of all emulated instructions to a logfile which has grown to 2.5 GB in 45 min.

I've only got 800 MB free. Can I truncate the file without disturbing the program writing to it? And if so, how?

This is running on Cygwin over Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`echo -n '' > /path/to/the/file` should replace the file with a 0-byte successor.  However, Windows file locking is nearly always a pain only when you don't want it to be.  If the program is maintaining an open file handle rather than a series of open-append-close events, this may not work.

Comment: Whew. That's better. 50 MB. Gotta wait 5 min. to accept. :)